# How to compare two list without inbuilt predicate?

Tags: prolog

I got a task of getting the list while executing and compare the list if the list has at least one matching element display false else displays true

I have tried with some inbuilt functions but could not able sort it out without them.

could someone help on this will be thankful

Expected results:

```
Set([1,2],[3,1]).
false

Set([2,3,4],[1,5,6]).
true
```

Comment: What do you mean by inbuilt? Also `(=)/2` and `dif/2` are built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
disjoint(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(list_without(Ys), Xs).

list_without([], _).
list_without([X|Xs], E) :-
   dif(X, E),
   list_without(Xs, E).
```

Alternatively without maplist:

```
disjoint(Xs, Ys) :-
   all_without(Xs, Ys).

all_without([], _).
all_without([X|Xs], Ys) :-
   list_without(Ys, X),
   all_without(Xs, Ys).
```